# Partial application of operators

Tags: function, haskell, types, currying, partial-application

If I want to add a space at the end of a character to return a list, how would I accomplish this with partial application if I am passing no arguments?

Also would the type be?

```
space :: Char -> [Char]
```

I'm having trouble adding a space at the end due to a 'parse error' by using the ++ and the : operators.

What I have so far is:

```
space :: Char -> [Char]
space = ++ ' '
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)? A [partial function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) is one which is undefined for some inputs.

Comment: I think it would be helpful, if you showed how you would use the function. Is it: `space "Hello" -- yields "Hello "`. If you want to use the function like that, the signature would be `space :: [Char] -> [Char]`. So it wouldn't contain just `Char` at all.

Answer (score 5):

Doing what you want is so common in Haskell it's got its own syntax, but being Haskell, it's extraordinarily lightweight. For example, this works:

```
space :: Char -> [Char]
space = (:" ")
```

so you weren't far off a correct solution. (`[Char]` is the same as `String`. `" "` is the string containing the character `' '`.) Let's look at using a similar function first to get the hang of it. There's a function in a library called `equalFilePath :: FilePath -> FilePath -> Bool`, which is used to test whether two filenames or folder names represent the same thing. (This solves the problem that on unix, `mydir` isn't the same as `MyDir`, but on Windows it is.) Perhaps I want to check a list to see if it's got the file I want:

```
isMyBestFile :: FilePath -> Bool
isMyBestFile fp = equalFilePath "MyBestFile.txt" fp
```

but since functions gobble their first argument first, then return a new function to gobble the next, etc, I can write that shorter as

```
isMyBestFile = equalFilePath "MyBestFile.txt"
```

This works because `equalFilePath "MyBestFile.txt"` is itself a function that takes one argument: it's type is `FilePath -> Bool`. This is partial application, and it's super-useful. Maybe I don't want to bother writing a seperate `isMyBestFile` function, but want to check whether any of my list has it:

```
hasMyBestFile :: [FilePath] -> Bool
hasMyBestFile fps = any (equalFilePath "MyBestFile.txt") fps
```

or just the partially applied version again:

```
hasMyBestFile = any (equalFilePath "MyBestFile.txt")
```

Notice how I need to put brackets round `equalFilePath "MyBestFile.txt"`, because if I wrote `any equalFilePath "MyBestFile.txt"`, then `filter` would try and use just `equalFilePath` without the `"MyBestFile.txt"`, because functions gobble their first argument first. `any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`

Now some functions are infix operators - taking their arguments from before and after, like `==` or `<`. In Haskell these are just regular functions, not hard-wired into the compiler (but have precedence and associativity rules specified). What if I was a unix user who never heard of `equalFilePath` and didn't care about the portability problem it solves, then I would probably want to do

```
hasMyBestFile = any ("MyBestFile.txt" ==)
```

and it would work, just the same, because == is a regular function. When you do that with an operator function, it's called an operator section.

It can work at the front or the back:

```
hasMyBestFile = any (== "MyBestFile.txt")
```

and you can do it with any operator you like:

```
hassmalls = any (< 5)
```

and a handy operator for lists is `:`. `:` takes an element on the left and a list on the right, making a new list of the two after each other, so `'Y':"es"` gives you `"Yes"`. (Secretly, `"Yes"` is actually just shorthand for `'Y':'e':'s':[]` because `:` is a constructor/elemental-combiner-of-values, but that's not relevant here.) Using `:` we can define

```
space c = c:" "
```

and we can get rid of the `c` as usual

```
space = (:" ")
```

which hopefully make more sense to you now.

Comment: `space = (++" ")` is definitely not `Char -> [Char]`

Comment: @Sarah First I deleted all reference to `(++" ")`, but now I've reinstated it (with the correct type!) because I think it's likely to be more useful.

Answer (score 4):

What you want here is an [operator section](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Section_of_an_infix_operator). For that, you'll need to surround the application with parentheses, i.e.

```
space = (: " ")
```

which is syntactic sugar for

```
space = (\x -> x : " ")
```

`(++)` won't work here because it expects a string as the first argument, compare:

```
(:)  :: a -> [a] -> [a]
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble understanding the concept behind this. If possible, can you please explain?

Comment: @user1670032: Sorry, my first solution was more complicated than necessary (I blame it on it being 3AM here). Take a look at the link I posted, there are more examples there.